# English phonology

Tags: grammar

A letter which is not pronounced is called silent, such as 'l' in "calm".

Two vowels occurring together are called a diphthong, such as 'ea' in "break".

What do we call a letter on which the word ends its sound, such as 'k' in "break"?

Comment: A diphthong is two vowels that combine to make a single phoneme. The last phoneme to end a word is *word-final*.

Comment: I would prefer the example of '*K*' in '*Knot*' to the '*L*' in '*Calm*'. Yes the '*L*' is silent, but it modifies the sound of the '*a*' - like magic '*e*'s

Comment: To clarify,  Which letter is the letter on which the words "make" or "cough" end their sound?